# When when I open and write to the executable it doesn't execute

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I have a NASM assembly program that when run will create an executable and execute it.

```
section .data  
    File db "Open",0  
section .text  
    global _start  

_start:  

mov rax, 2 ; Open the file/ Create it
mov rdi, File
mov rsi, 65
mov rdx, 777
syscall
push rax

mov rdi, rax ; Write to the file
mov rax, 1
mov rsi, 0x600300 ; Location of where the appended data is
mov rdx, 900
syscall

mov rax, 3 ; Close the file
pop rdi
syscall

mov rax, 59  ; Execute the file
mov rdi, File
syscall

mov rax, 60 ; Close out of the program
mov rdi, 0
syscall
```

I have tried to Execute the file before I close the file and I get the same output(nothing). The file that I write is an executable in the proper format and if I run ./Open it prints out Hello. If I just make a simple program like

```
section .data
    File db "Open", 0

section .text  
    global _start  

_start:  

mov rax, 59  ; Execute the file
mov rdi, File
syscall
```

It executes the program just as I would like it to.  Why when I open the file first and write to it it doesn't execute it?  To clarify I appended the executable that is being written at 0x300 and the written file is executable.

Comment: Accidental. You do realize syscall 59 (execve) needs a bunch of other arguments apart from the file name, right? PS: use `strace` to see what you actually did. Also, check returned error codes.

Comment: Thanks the rsi, and rdx registers were carrying over causing the error.